# Is there any difference between adb wait-for-device and adb wait-for-devices?

Tags: android, adb

There are two commands that I used wait for a device to come up:
adb wait-for-device and adb wait-for-devices.
Both seem to wait for a device to boot up, I din't find any difference in their behaviour. Is there any difference in their behaviour?
Adding more information on what I did:
So here is what I did, from the android documentation I used adb wait-for-device but then sometime while using this command I used it as adb wait-for-devices, as you can see I added a extra 's' at the end, but the command still worked. So I was thinking why does both wait-for-device and wait-for-devices work! Why would android provide two commands for the same?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html
where exactly do you see this wait-for-devices command?

Comment: I typed devices and worked! Alex below explained the reason. Why are people downvoting the answer??

Comment: Probably because they aren't able to find the commands in the documentation, a link would be useful. The question is also being flagged as too broad, you could point to the documentation and ask for something more specific. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how `adb` handles the command:

```
 /* handle wait-for-* prefix */
if (!strncmp(argv[0], "wait-for-", strlen("wait-for-"))) {
    const char* service = argv[0];
    if (!strncmp(service, "wait-for-device", strlen("wait-for-device"))) {
        if (ttype == kTransportUsb) {
            service = "wait-for-usb";
        } else if (ttype == kTransportLocal) {
            service = "wait-for-local";
        } else {
            service = "wait-for-any";
        }
    }
```

So any string starting with `wait-for-device` would have the same effect

Comment: Did not know this! Thanks!
Why are people down voting the question??