# error: unknown host service for adb wait-for-devices

Tags: android, adb

When I run this

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
ABCD1234    device
```

I get a normal reply. But this doesn't return anything

```
$ adb wait-for-devices
error: unknown host service
error: unknown host service
```

Usb debugging is enabled.

Comment: it's `adb wait-for-device`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29968795/1778421

Answer (score 1):

In older `adb` versions there was just one `wait-for-` option and any single command line argument starting with `wait-for-device` would trigger it. I.e. `wait-for-device` and `wait-for-devices` used to do the same thing. But recently  new functionality has been added:

```
adb wait-for[-<transport>]-<state>
                           - wait for device to be in the given state:
                             device, recovery, sideload, or bootloader
                             Transport is: usb, local or any [default=any]
```

So obviously the old command line parsing code has been replaced with the new one - which is looking for the exact match (instead of just beginning of the string). The bottom line is that `wait-for-devices` no longer works. If you used that variant in your scripts - you need to change it to the official `wait-for-device`.